# Query not fetching results in Grails/MongoDB App

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, findall

I am developing an app in grails and mongodb. I am facing a very weird error. My controller class is as follows:

```
def report()
{
def website ="http://www.downloadaudiosongs.com/?dir&page=all"
def res = Resource.findAllByWebsite(website)
int noOfResources = res.size()
println noOfResources
}
```

This shows me noOfResources as 0.
This same findAllByWebsite query works in mongoDB and shows me the appropriate records.

```
 db.resource.find({ "website": "http://www.downloadaudiosongs.com/?dir&page=all"})
```

But in my grails app, it doesn't fetch any records for this value of website where as for some other value, it does. I tried grails clean but nothing helped. Can anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Edit: So I think I know what is causing the issue. The ? symbol in the url is doing it because db.resource.find works for all other urls except the ones with ? and special characters. Please correct me if my understanding is flawed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would seem something is wrong with the `.findAllByWebsite()` method you have implemented. But the code for that is not posted here so we cannot see what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I didnot implement this method. Its provided by GORM. check an example here: http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20(GORM).html#5.2.3 Inheritance in GORM

Comment: Didn't see the tag. Is the type not possibly a string but something else? So the class definition might help here.

Comment: Its always a string. I manually checked it still it doesn't work

Comment: Please post the domain structure code for further debugging.